# Intermittent Black Lines in Flash Video

Tags: flash

We've been having intermittent black lines in some of Flash videos on our development site. Our Flash developer has ruled out any obvious problems in the code, which I have to take his word for.

My question is how would I go about figuring out what the cause of this is or at least the potential causes. As I mentioned, it is intermittent, and I haven't been able to determine any pattern.

I'm sorry to be so vague. But I'm looking for general approaches so I can tackle this rather than expecting someone to know the cause of this type of problem.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while, but I thought I would add the answer for historical purposes. Another developer discovered some sort of JavaScript or HTML bug on the page. Once corrected, the lines went away. Why that translates into black lines on a flash bug is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 0):

OK. No one has really answered this so I'll give it a try.

Its an odd scenario - but

1. Maybe the video card on the machine your running
2. Could be glitches in the browser your using
3. Issues with the network itself - streaming HD Content maybe?
4. The video file itself has corrupt pixel data. Dependant upon your encoding type and setup]

My preference is the latter of these points but if you could explain the issue further that'd be more helpful.

- How big are the lines?
- where are they on the screen?
- what type of intermittent, is it per video file just random or once in a blue moon?
- how long are they on the screen?
- What type of video file is it?
- How long is the video?
- What setup do you have?
- Are you using an off the shelf player or custom made?

Answer these I'm sure we'll get to the bottom of the problem.